# How to remove image hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with some icons with a hover/overlay effect, but somehow the two icons on the right have a weird effect that pushes the image to the top right. I want the hover effect to be like the icon on the left. I used .gif images for all the icons.

How can I change the effect so it behaves like the icon on the left (profile)?

```css
nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7dc623;
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 color: #7dc623;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #7dc623;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
  }

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 68px;
}

.navicons2 {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navicons3  {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="test.html">Nu bestellen</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">Zo werkt het</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="test.html">Recepten</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="test.html">Op het menu</a>
      <a href="test.html">Alle recepten</a> 
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      
  <div class="iconwrap">
    <div class="navicons1">
    <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif"/></div>
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
      </div>
   <div class="navicons2">
      <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
      </div>
    <div class="navicons3">
      <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLs1Ipo.gif" alt="winkelwagen"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on hover you were changing the position of your item by margin-top and margin-left, that was causing this effect, just remove that

```css
nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7dc623;
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 color: #7dc623;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #7dc623;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
  }

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2 {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navicons3  {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="test.html">Nu bestellen</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">Zo werkt het</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="test.html">Recepten</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="test.html">Op het menu</a>
      <a href="test.html">Alle recepten</a> 
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      
  <div class="iconwrap">
    <div class="navicons1">
    <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif"/></div>
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
      </div>
   <div class="navicons2">
      <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
      </div>
    <div class="navicons3">
      <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLs1Ipo.gif" alt="winkelwagen"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so simple!

Answer (score 1):

I just delete part of your code (transition):

```css
nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7dc623;
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 color: #7dc623;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #7dc623;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
  }

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;

}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;

}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 68px;
}

.navicons2 {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navicons3  {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="test.html">Nu bestellen</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">Zo werkt het</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="test.html">Recepten</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="test.html">Op het menu</a>
      <a href="test.html">Alle recepten</a> 
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      
  <div class="iconwrap">
    <div class="navicons1">
    <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif"/></div>
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
      </div>
   <div class="navicons2">
      <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
      </div>
    <div class="navicons3">
      <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLs1Ipo.gif" alt="winkelwagen"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin-top & left from .naviconshov2 and .naviconshov3

```css
nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7dc623;
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 color: #7dc623;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #7dc623;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
  }

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2 {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navicons3  {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="test.html">Nu bestellen</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">Zo werkt het</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="test.html">Recepten</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="test.html">Op het menu</a>
      <a href="test.html">Alle recepten</a> 
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      
  <div class="iconwrap">
    <div class="navicons1">
    <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif"/></div>
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
      </div>
   <div class="navicons2">
      <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
      </div>
    <div class="navicons3">
      <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLs1Ipo.gif" alt="winkelwagen"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) CSS attributes set for icons:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
```

just remove those lines and you are good to go:

```css
nav {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 200px;
 font-size: 1em;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 width: auto;
}

nav li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #7dc623;
}

nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.active {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 130px;
 margin-top: -1px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 color: #7dc623;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
 color: #7dc623;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #7dc623;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.iconwrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 380px;
  }

.navicons1, .navicons2, .navicons3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #7dc623;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.naviconshov1, .naviconshov2, .naviconshov3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navicons1:hover .naviconshov1 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navicons2:hover .naviconshov2 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

.navicons3:hover .naviconshov3 {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 68px;
}

.navicons2 {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.navicons3  {
  margin-top: -34px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="test.html">Nu bestellen</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">Zo werkt het</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="test.html">Recepten</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="test.html">Op het menu</a>
      <a href="test.html">Alle recepten</a> 
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
      
  <div class="iconwrap">
    <div class="navicons1">
    <div class="naviconshov1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FMb2eun.gif"/></div>
        <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6w5w1r8.gif" alt="account"/></a>
      </div>
   <div class="navicons2">
      <div class="naviconshov2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/QGZVEQl.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1eY8XZN.gif" alt="favorieten"/></a>
      </div>
    <div class="navicons3">
      <div class="naviconshov3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ueXdZR8.gif"/></div>
      <a href="test.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eLs1Ipo.gif" alt="winkelwagen"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```